# Want to show the response text message ajax success function on another view page

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo site_url(); ?>/Barcodescanner/Prepare_Csv_File",
    data:{
        po_number : po_number 
    },
    success:function(response){
        // alert(response);
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>Barcodescanner?PO_Number=<?php echo $po_number; ?>';
            var success = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible"><p><b>Success: </b>Prepared file for PO Number, <a href="/public/log_files/Barcode_Scanner_Report_File/'+response+'">Download</a></p><a style="margin-right: 13px;font-weight: bold;" href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a></div>';
                
             $("#response_msg").html(success);
        }
        
    }
});
```

I want to show that `response_msg` on the redirect page. I know how to show `response_msg` on the same page, but how can I show it on another page?

Comment: You can attached `response` in url i,e : `'<?php echo base_url(); ?>Barcodescanner?PO_Number=<?php echo $po_number; ?>&response='+response;` then build your  divs at your redirected page . Using `$_GET['response']` get value and add them to your html .

Comment: how can I make runnable. 

<div class="row">
<div id="response_msg"></div>
</div>

Comment: In URL I don't want to make any changes

Comment: Then put that value in `sessions` if you need that in your redirected page .

Comment: @Aravindaswamy M if you use ajax then why you redirect page resonse??

Comment: want to show the response message on another page after the redirection

Answer (score 0):

You can Set `session` and check if there is a `$_SESSION['msg']` set on the page you are redirecting it to, if set then alert on another page.

**jQuery / AJAX :-**

```
     <script>
 
    success:function(response){
                  
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>Barcodescanner?PO_Number=<?php echo $po_number; ?>';
        
    }
                    
    }
    });
</script>
```

**Then, $po_number page:**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
  echo '$(document).ready(function(){
            alert('.$_SESSION['msg'].');
        })';
}
```